# How to show that $\{X \le Y\}$ is an event?

Tags: probability-theory

Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, then $\{X \le Y \} $ is an event. I am studying pre-measure probability theory and only the simplest definitions are known.

*My approach:*
I know that a random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is such that for any $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$, $X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F}$. Where $B$ is a member of the Borel Sets on the real line.

For a single random variable, I could say that for any $t \in \mathbb R$, $\{X^{-1}(B)\} \in \mathcal{A}$, where $\{X^{-1}(B)\} = X^{-1}((-\infty, t]))$, ( so every $X^{-1}$ is an event...). I'm not sure how to extend this to show that $\{X\le Y\}$, is also an event; I feel like I am missing something really simple.

Thanks!

Comment: By $(X\leq Y)$, do you mean the function that returns $1$ if $X\leq Y$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: Sorry about that, I had asked something different than what I wanted to say, which is, that $X \le Y$ is an event.

Comment: I don't get that $X\leq Y$ is an event. A random variable is a mapping...so what do you exactly mean with $X\leq Y$?

Comment: I believe that it means that an event $w: X(w) \le Y(w)$, I was hoping someone would have some insight on this and I believe it is largely the source of my confusion with this problem.

Comment: I think he means that the set $\{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega) \leq Y(\omega)\}$ is measurable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $X\leq Y$ if and only if, for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, we have $X\leq q$ or $Y\geq q$. It follows that
$$
\{X\leq Y\}=\bigcap_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}\left(\{X\leq q\}\cup \{Y\geq q\}\right)
$$
is a countable intersection of measureable sets, so is measureable.

Answer (score 4):

$Z=X-Y$ is again a random variable. $X\leq Y$ is equivalent to $Z\leq0$, and $Z^{-1}((-\infty,0])$ is an event.

Answer (score 0):

As a real random vector, (X,Y) is a function from some probability space to R^2 such that pre-images of Borel sets are events in the space. In this context, {X<=Y} is the pre-image of points in the plane R^2 on and above the line y=x, which is a Borel set (e.g., it is closed).